# Replace '%20' with '-' in url for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, url

I am having some issues with replacing '%20' with '-' in a generated url.  Basically, I have a book search form that matches the users input with a database and a display page then populates with the matching books.  The user can then click on a 'View more' button on the display page and that direct them to that specific item's page (populating with the attributes via the database).

On the display page, I have the following lines to pass the name of the item to the url when the users clicked on the 'View more':

```
<td><br><a href="/books/<%=book.bookname%>">View More</a>
```

The routes file would have this line:

```
match '/books/:display_book', to: 'books#show', via:'get'
```

The parameter, :display_book, will then be passed into the controller file:

```
@displaybook=Book.find_by(bookname: params[:display_book])
```

and then the page, /books/<%=book.bookname%>, will displays the specific books attributes.

The issue exists in the above line, when <%=book.bookname%>, is passed into the url.  Some books have spaces and capital letters in the database. It would be best to replace the spaces with dashes and make all upper case letters to lower case letters in the url.  However, doing this will cause the parameter to not be matched in the controller file.  What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to take a look at Friendly ID - https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

If you apply the gem you are going to create a new attribute in your books table named "slug".

The slug will automatically be generated with hyphens (-). So in your case if you have the book titled "The girl who saved the king of Sweden" it will create the following slug on creation: "the-girl-who-saved-the-king-of-sweden". I suppose currently you also have the issue of upper case letters in your url - which doesn't harm but isn't clean. So that problem would disappear as well :)

PS: It also helps to create unique slugs in case you have duplicated titles. For example if you have books on your site with the same title but different publishers or different publishing date you can then define slug candidates - which means that in case another entry exists with the same slug, you would like to add another attribute.

Here is an example:

```
#models/book.rb 
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

private
def slug_candidates
  [  :title
     [:title, :publisher],
     [:title, :publisher, :publish_date]
  ]
end
```

Here's the detailed instruction for rails 4: http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/4.0/

Comment: Also it makes your life very easy searching for specific entries in your controllers. For example show action: @book = Book.friendly.find(params[:id]) ... no need to change anything other than place "friendly" after the model

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know which letters could be upper case, it is not safe to assume that you can convert back and forth between real name and URL-safe names.  I will give an outline of the solution; pardon that I don't have time for writing the code for you.

- In the `Book` model, create an `after_filter` on the `create` method, which

  - takes the book name and converts it to a URL-safe-name of your choosing.
  - Check for duplicate names before saving, and increment the name or create another unique variant
- use the url-safe name in your links
- use the url-safe name for lookup of the book
- only display the normal name

This solution lets you avoid ID values, which will not create memorable nor attractive URLs.